# Change the adapter of a spinner on runtime using onItemSelectedListener

Tags: android, spinner

This is my code

```
[...]
final String[] top_spinner_items = new String[35];
for (int i = 0; i < top_spinner_items.length; i++) {
    top_spinner_items[i] = Integer.toString(i+1);
}
ArrayAdapter<String> spn_topItemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, top_spinner_items);
spn_topItemsAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
[...]



AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener lst_bottomSpinner_changed_element = new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
        //
        final String[] top_spinner_items = new String[35];
        for (int i = 0; i < top_spinner_items.length; i++) {
            top_spinner_items[i] = Integer.toString(i+1);
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> spn_topItemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, top_spinner_items);
        spn_topItemsAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
        // your code here
    }

};
```

(all the missing references are in the code are between or before the code)

My question is why inside AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener

```
ArrayAdapter<String> spn_topItemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, top_spinner_items);
```

gives error. It says "the constructor is undefined". I tryed using android.widget.ArrayAdapter, but got none.
I'm trying to change the adapter of a spinner when a previous spinner is changed(i want the second spinner to have the value setted in the previous one)

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got a compile error because you pass an instance of `AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener` to the constructor of the adapter instead of context. Modify your code in `onItemSelected`, adding classname of your `Activity` before `this`:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> spn_topItemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(YourActivity.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, top_spinner_items);
```

And, you missed setting the adapter to your `ListView` in `inItemSelected`, like `parentView.setAdapter(spn_topItemsAdapter);`.
However, I think, changing whole adapter in `onItemSelected` isn't a good idea. You'd better modify the existing one.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to modify it(if it isn't too long or complex to explain here)?

Comment: It heavily depends on your purposes. You can use methods `add`, `insert` and `remove` for this.